# C++ Setting std::tuple values in an std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, data-structures, unordered-map, stdtuple

I have an unordered map with string keys and a tuple of three strings and one int. How can I access the individual tuples to set them.

Given:

```
std::unordered_map<string,std::tuple<string, string, string,int>> foo_data_by_username;
```

How can I set the individual tuple values of say `foo_data_by_username[some_user];`

Comment: Beware that using tuples can infect your code with magic numbers (`std::get<0>` -- what is "0" supposed to mean)? You might be better off using a custom POD type so that you can give each piece of data a useful name, as well as the ability to add/remove members without having to adjust tuple indices everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::get<0>(foo_data_by_username[some_user]) = "new string";
```

Where `0` is whichever index of the tuple you're interested in.

Comment: Related documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get